# NSTextField on top of a NSVisualEffectView with wantsLayer aliasing issue

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nstextfield, nsvisualeffectview

I'm aware that you must have a solid background color behind a NSTextField when using Core Animation layers (CALayer) as sub-pixel is not supported, however I need to use a `NSVisualEffectView` behind my `NSOutlineView` and I'm using several NSTextFields on top. If I set `wantsLayer` to YES for the `NSOutlineView`, sadly the text on top becomes poorly aliased. How can I get the nice blur AND smooth text on top? Does this mean we can't use `CALayer` at all when using `NSVisualEffectView` as it's superview?

Comment: I've tried something similar and had all sorts of rendering problems with text fields on a effects view. However I changed to the source list style (which sets up the effects view automatically) and this solved all the display problems, at least in my case. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Apparently there are known font smoothing issues in 10.10 and this isn't possible to do till it's fixed.

Comment: Oh interesting. Do you have a reference for that, I'd like to read more.

Comment: I got a reply from Corbin (Apple) on dev forums for this question saying there are known issues with text smoothing although inside a Visual Effects view it should work, but he pointed out this could be a bug (as I've found other known bugs with visual effects view when used with a NSSplitView)

Comment: Oh I'll take a look at the apple lists. Thanks!

Comment: I can second this bug. I'm using NSTextField on top of a NSVisualEffectView, it renders its text very strangely when within a selected NSTableViewRow.

Comment: @strangetimes Is it fixed? I got similar in 2018 =( Smoothing does not work for CALayered subviews. NSButton and NSTextField.

Comment: @ZevsVU not quite - just try and make sure anything with text inside is backed by an opaque solid background. A standard NSTextField inside of NSVisuaEffectView should mostly work as long as you're not doing anything 'customized' inside. There are limitations in how it renders text on macOS compared to iOS.